# specify a table in a database in redshift

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

Very new to Redshift and currently doing a micro-benchmarking on Redshift comparing to the in-house old database "MySQL".

Is there anyway in Redshift that we can specify a table in a database in redshift?

In MySQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;

CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name (blah blah);

SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name;
```

In Redshift it will fail:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: schema "database_name" does not exist;
```

Could any guru enlighten?

Thanks!

Comment: Redshift is not mysql.

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual, each database has one defaulted schema and it is name `PUBLIC`. You need to qualify the schema name when creating tables.

Please see the following manual pages:

[Schemas](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Schemas_and_tables.html) and [CREATE SCHEMA](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_SCHEMA.html) and [CREATE TABLE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html) and [CREATE DATABASE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_DATABASE.html)

Comment: Correct. When you connect to a `DATABASE` in Redshift, you are *in* that database. You cannot refer to other databases. Instead, there is the additional `schema` layer, that can differentiate tables between users.